# How do I make ScrollView auto scroll to the bottom?

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

How can i make it once the `ScrollView` is out of the screen it will auto scroll to the bottom?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307267/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-in-a-scrollview-on-activity-startup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code to achieve your task :-

```
scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

or

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
```

Comment: can we use speed for scrolling?

Comment: yes, finally I controlled the time by using a runnable by internals. that the right way, right?

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work

```
scrollView.post {
   scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                 scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
               }
});
```

This worked for me