# ScrollView scroll to bottom issue

Tags: java, android

I have tried with ScrollView FOCUS_DOWN but not scrolling to the bottom, it scrolls near bottom. It must be done after adding a LinearLayout element.

My code:

```
LinearLayoutView.addView(txtView);
scroll.addView(LinearLayoutView);   
scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check this out [the previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3310376/1129468)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed using the following code:

```
scroll.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
    public void run() {
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below code ..

```
scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom());
```

this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a message type thing that you want to scroll to the bottom when ever there is something new you can use this:

```
this.getListView().setStackFromBottom(true);
this.getListView().setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL)
```

This is for a `ListActivity`, but just replace `this.getListView()` with the list view in question