# How to make Android textview selectable and scrolled to bottom (by default)?

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have a textview which text must be selectable `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` and scrollable to bottom by default `textView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance())`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorScreenBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.xxxx.xxxx.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="7dip"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:background="@color/gray_background"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
            android:background="@color/gray_background"
            />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the `setMovementMethod` disable the textview selectability.

How to solve this?

NB: The principal feature required here is that not only the textview must be scrollable, but it must also appeared **initially scrolled to bottom** by default, and this is provided by the `setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance())`, according to [How to get the Android TextView to scroll down to the end automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826693/how-can-i-make-a-textview-automatically-scroll-as-i-add-more-lines-of-text).

Comment: Remove setMovementMethod, android:textIsSelectable have the scrolling property in it.

Comment: The setMovementMethod is needed to make the textview auto scroll down when a text is appended. This functionality is required.

Comment: @ShamirKp, so it is not possible to have a textview having the two properties : selectable and auto scroll to bottom ?

Comment: Please share the full layout xml so that i can check, because android:textIsSelectable have both selectable and scroll property to it.

Comment: @ShamirKp, done!

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1):

Put your text view inside an scroll view in your xml

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Then do this in your class

```
//This will scroll to bottom 
ScrollView scrollView=findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
```