# How to display last textview in linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Any idea to display the last textview inside a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`?

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.qianonnphoon.tradeal.chat.ChatActivity"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
layout="@layout/message_area"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`TextView` will be added to `layout1` when receive the data. So I will have multiple textviews in `layout1` once finish loading. However, it display the first `TextView` then I need to scroll down to see the last `TextView`. Any idea to display the last `TextView` when it finish loading?

This is the code how I add `TextView` when receive data

```
TextView textView = new TextView(ChatActivity.this);
    textView.setText(message);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    if(type == 1) {
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
    }
    else{
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner2);
    }

    layout.addView(textView);
    scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Comment: why **android:layout_weight="20"** to scrollview

Comment: @NileshRathod because I am just follow tutorial to create this, haven't change yet. But is it the cause that it won't display last textview first?

Comment: I think this answer will help you out: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310376/8837156>

Comment: may be just try my below ans and let me know it works or not @phoon

Comment: May I know why is this question down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me

```
final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview));
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```